# Listing Web Cam Properties using Win RT

Tags: windows-runtime

I am developing the metro style application using Win RT.
I Need to List the Properties of Web Cam Like Frame rate ,Size and format it supports .
A web Cam Can Support multiple Frame rate ,Size and format, I wanted to list all of it.
I am exploring Windows Runtime Reference but couldn't figure out the Api which will give those information.

Any Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows.Media.Devices.VideoDeviceController has a GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties method which returns supported formats. The rest isn't built into WinRT yet, but it you can bet will. It's just not there yet.